# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Object>' to 'UnityEngine.Object'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am quite new to Unity and C#, and I am trying to parse a json file to an Experiment object in Unity, but I keep getting this error message from the Debug.Log line saying that;

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Experiment>' to 'UnityEngine.Object'
```

This is my load json code, using the JSON .NET for Unity asset. My json file is structured as an array of objects.

```cs
public void LoadJson()
  {
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("exMercury.json"))
    {
      string json = r.ReadToEnd();
      List<Experiment> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Experiment>>(json);
      Debug.Log("Experimenter ", items);
    }
  }
```

The json file:

```json
{
  "experiments": [
    {
      "Title": "A title",
      "Ingredients": "list of ingredients",
      "Description": "description",
      "Points": 100,
      "Completed": false,
      "Steps": [
        "step 1",
        "step 2",
        "step 3",
      ],
      "Hypothesis": "",
      "Explanation": "",
      "Progress": 0.0
    },
]
}
```

The struct for experiments;

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Firebase.Firestore;

[FirestoreData]
public struct Experiment
{
  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Description { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public List<string> Ingredients { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public List<string> Steps { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public int Points { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public bool Completed { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Hypothesis { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public string Explanation { get; set; }

  [FirestoreProperty]
  public float Progress { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the code you have shown here that would throw an exception like that?

Comment: Unless it's the `Debug.Log` line, I don't know Unity well enough to know what that overload is supposed to be doing.

Comment: The debug log is the only place shown it could be, is the log expecting a UnityEngine.Object

Comment: Oops, my bad, the error is in the Debug.Log line

Comment: Does your JSON file have a `"$type"` property anywhere in it? You're using JSON.NET (Jewtonsoft.Json), which allows for types to be indicated with that special property. It may be specifying `"UnityEngine.Object"` for the root object.

Comment: Nope, have not tried with the "$type" property, I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Not asking you to add it... asking if it already exists anywhere in the file. Can you show a snippet of it, perhaps the first few lines of it (formatted)?

Comment: I've added it to the post now :)

Comment: Since you top level element in your json is an object with a property called experiments you should also reflect this when deserializing meaning you should have a class holding your list of experiment

Comment: I'm not sure where `"UnityEngine.Object"` is coming from, but you need a wrapper object with an "experiments" property. This question has been asked many times in one form or another but I'm still looking for an existing answer.

Comment: or adjust the json to only hold the experiment array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1\[obJson\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796486/cannot-deserialize-json-object-into-type-system-collections-generic-list1objs)

Comment: Plus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275097/the-json-value-could-not-be-converted-to-system-collections-generic-list

Comment: So the error you have is because you're using the `Debug.Log` method incorrectly. Though @madreflection is also correct, that is not what you are asking here.

Comment: I've retracted my duplicate vote because @DavidG is correct about the `Debug.Log` call, but I'll leave the links there because you're still going to need those.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, think I'll manage to figure it out now! @madreflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) takes as parameters

```
public static void Log(object message, Object context);
```

where `Object` refers to [`UnityEngnie.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) and well as the error tells you a `List<Experiment>` is not a `UnityEngine.Object`.

The actual purpose of mentioned `UnityEngine.Object context` parameter is the following:

If this is e.g. called in a `MonoBehaviour` you can add

```
Debug.Log(someMessage, this);
```

using the component itself as context meaning when you click on the logged message once in Unity the according object will get highlighted in the Hierarchy or assets (for ScriptableObjects etc). This way you can pass in anything inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` (`GameObject`, `Component`, `ScriptableObject`, `Texture2D`, `Material`, ....) and make it pingable.

---

Now I can of course only guess but I think what you actually want to achieve would be

- Implement [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) for your `Experiment` class so it prints out the desired information
- And then use e.g.

  ```
  // convert all items into their according string representation
  // see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select
  var strings = items.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
  // combine all individual string into a single one using whatever separator character you want
  // see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join
  var debugString = string.Join("\n\n", strings);
  // finally log this
  Debug.Log("Experiments: \n\n" + debugString);
  ```

or if you just want to check if it worked at all you could probably simply do

```
Debug.Log($"Successfully loaded {items.Count} Experiments!");
```